# encoding in vim all messed up

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I have tex file that used to work in Vim but now I have to run

```
:e ++enc=utf16 /path/to/file.tex
```

to view the file correctly.

If I do

```
:write ++enc=utf-8 /path/to/file.tex,
```

the file is in Chinese (I don't know why).

How can I change the encoding so I don't need to run `:e ++enc=utf16` every time?

Comment: if you do `:w ++enc=utf-8....` then what?? and, why your `:w...` line ending with a comma? and...We don't know why the file is in Chinese either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked: `:set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,sjis`